# Two classes as argument of a class function

Tags: c++, function, class

I know the title is twisted, but I couldn't think of a different wat to say it. I need to write a class function that uses two class objects as arguments. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class list{
private:
    struct ele{
        int num;
        ele *next;
        ele(){
            next=0;
        }
    };

public:
    list();
    ele *first;
    void add (int num);
    void print();
    void dod(list a, list b);
```

};

```
void list::dod(list a, list b){
a->print();
b->print();
```

}

I don't know why, but this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're asking here, we can assume it doesn't work. Please give more information, as that description adds nearly nothing.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a meaningful way to express what is going on.  Please clarify what is happening and what you expected.

Comment: But it works - of course after adding a way to print(`std::cout`) and fixing syntax errors(lacking `}` in `print` and `print2`).

Comment: Sorry for not explaining more. I'm writing a program that uses a list to add two numbers. The idea is that I import the two numbers as two separate lists of digits, sum them and print them out.

Comment: That still doesn't explain "doesn't seem to work"

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't compile or doesn't run?

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error, include the full error in your post.  If you're getting unexpected runtime behavior, then include both the expected and actual observed behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You use `->` to access members of pointers, not objects. For objects, you use `.`.

Change

```
void list::dod(list a, list b){
   a->print();
   b->print();
}
```

to

```
void list::dod(list a, list b){
   a.print(); // Not -> but .
   b.print(); // Same thing.
}
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem. I needed to change `void list::dod(list a, list b){` to `void list::dod(list *a, list *b){`

Comment: @photons3432 But that *was* the problem.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you access class members:

```
list object;
object.print();

list* pointer;
pointer->print();
```